# Error: free(): invalid next size (fast) and Aborted (core dumped) while using R in Linux server

Tags: r, linux

I am using R (v4.1) in my Linux server with Ubuntu 22.04.2. I want to use the function `processBismarkAln` from the package MethylKit to read my `.sam` files (output from BisMark). The bam files are ~8 GB in size. The server has a RAM of ~250 GB. When the running the function, an output file is created but is incomplete and is only of 100 kb.

After that this error message is displayed:

```
free(): invalid next size (fast)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

At first there was already some issue related to `.sam` file sorting but the error is persists even after this is rectified. If ran properly the function is supposed to output CpG reports of more than ~1 GB.

When I browsed about this error in Google I understood that is something related to memory corruption. Since I am using an R package and didn't write my own code I don't understand how to rectify this error.

Hope someone would help me solve this.

Thank you.